# How to use UART receive data for further processing rather than just echoing in embedded C?

Tags: c, embedded

Here is the code from my test environment. it simply replies back (echo) the entered data to the terminal application where it is connected through a Serial Port. So far so good.

Now, I need to use that data and process as per the requirements/protocol.
But, I am struggling to consume the data `UART0Buffer` as I expected.
(The variable `UART0Buffer` is populated in the UART Interrupt)

I send e.g. "7E0007AA010203040506CC" from the terminal
and the code replies back this to the terminal application in an order in four steps for some reason;

> 1 by Process #1

37

> 2 by Process #2

00

> 3 by Process #1

30 30 30 37 41 41 30 31 30 32 30 33 30 34 30

> 4 by Process #2

A1

As you can also notice that the data replied (echoed) is not identical with what I send from the terminal.

And furthermore, if I remove line "Process #2" completely,
I can get a proper echo;

`37 45 30 30 30 37 41 41 30 31 30 32 30 33 30 34 30 35 30 36 43 43`

What am I really missing here?

```
int main()
{
    SystemInit();       /* Clock and PLL configuration */   
    UARTInit(0, 57600); /* baud rate setting */

    while(1)
    {
        if ( UART0Count != 0 )
        {
            LPC_UART0->IER = IER_THRE | IER_RLS;            /* Disable RBR */

            UARTSend( 0, (uint8_t *)UART0Buffer, UART0Count ); // Process #1

            UART0Count = 0;

// I need to call a function here in order to process data in UART0Buffer
// like checking/using STX, CHKSUM and DATA.

            // A test, if I can manage to use the data in pieces
            UARTSend( 0, (uint8_t *)UART0Buffer[0], 1); // Process #2

            LPC_UART0->IER = IER_THRE | IER_RLS | IER_RBR;  /* Re-enable RBR */
        }
    }
}

void UARTSend( uint32_t portNum, uint8_t *BufferPtr, uint32_t Length )
{
  if ( portNum == 0 )
  {
    while ( Length != 0 )
    {
      /* THRE status, contain valid data */
      while ( !(UART0TxEmpty & 0x01) ); 
      LPC_UART0->THR = *BufferPtr;
      UART0TxEmpty = 0; /* not empty in the THR until it shifts out */
      BufferPtr++;
      Length--;
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
As dude has already explained the wrong use of "Process #2", please ignore it. It somehow breaks things. However, my issue persists. Although I can get an echo by "Process #1", I couldn't manage to read and use the data!?! Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Receiving:

```
void UART0_IRQHandler (void) 
{
  uint8_t IIRValue, LSRValue;
  uint8_t Dummy = Dummy;

  IIRValue = LPC_UART0->IIR;

  IIRValue >>= 1;           /* skip pending bit in IIR */
  IIRValue &= 0x07;         /* check bit 1~3, interrupt identification */
  if ( IIRValue == IIR_RLS )        /* Receive Line Status */
  {
    LSRValue = LPC_UART0->LSR;
    /* Receive Line Status */
    if ( LSRValue & (LSR_OE|LSR_PE|LSR_FE|LSR_RXFE|LSR_BI) )
    {
      /* There are errors or break interrupt */
      /* Read LSR will clear the interrupt */
      UART0Status = LSRValue;
      Dummy = LPC_UART0->RBR;       /* Dummy read on RX to clear 
                            interrupt, then bail out */
      return;
    }
    if ( LSRValue & LSR_RDR )   /* Receive Data Ready */            
    {
      /* If no error on RLS, normal ready, save into the data buffer. */
      /* Note: read RBR will clear the interrupt */
      UART0Buffer[UART0Count] = LPC_UART0->RBR;
      UART0Count++;
      if ( UART0Count == BUFSIZE )
      {
        UART0Count = 0;     /* buffer overflow */
      } 
    }
  }
  else if ( IIRValue == IIR_RDA )   /* Receive Data Available */
  {
    /* Receive Data Available */
    UART0Buffer[UART0Count] = LPC_UART0->RBR;
    UART0Count++;
    if ( UART0Count == BUFSIZE )
    {
      UART0Count = 0;       /* buffer overflow */
    }
  }
  else if ( IIRValue == IIR_CTI )   /* Character timeout indicator */
  {
    /* Character Time-out indicator */
    UART0Status |= 0x100;       /* Bit 9 as the CTI error */
  }
  else if ( IIRValue == IIR_THRE )  /* THRE, transmit holding register empty */
  {
    /* THRE interrupt */
    LSRValue = LPC_UART0->LSR;      /* Check status in the LSR to see if
                                    valid data in U0THR or not */
    if ( LSRValue & LSR_THRE )
    {
      UART0TxEmpty = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      UART0TxEmpty = 0;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: `(uint8_t *)UART0Buffer[0]` is *very* wrong. Here you tell the compiler that the first element of `UART0Buffer` itself is a pointer to some data. Which it isn't. You want `(uint8_t *)&UART0Buffer[0]` which is a pointer to the first element (and what plain `UART0Buffer` will decay to, like you have in "Process #1").

Comment: Thank you for your input dude. If we ignore that "Process #2", for example, how would you extract values of the first and third bytes?

Comment: *Assuming* (since you don't show its declaration or definition) that `UART0Buffer` is an array of bytes, you simply use normal array indexing to get the values you need. Like `UART0Buffer[1]` to get the second byte.

Comment: Dude, this is definiton of the variable; `extern volatile uint8_t UART0Buffer[0x40];`
If I try to get the values using such lines it is not making sense.
            `uint8_t dataIdx0 = UART0Buffer[0];
            uint8_t dataIdx1 = UART0Buffer[1];
            uint8_t dataIdx2 = UART0Buffer[2];
            uint8_t dataIdx3 = UART0Buffer[3];`
For example, I can't get value 37 from `UART0Buffer[0]` but zero or some random. Besides, `if ( UART0Count != 0 )` runs twice and next time another value. But that line `UARTSend( 0, (uint8_t *)UART0Buffer, UART0Count );` prints well. I am confused.

Comment: Doesn't `UARTSend` send data? How do you *receive* any data to process?

Comment: The entire buffer hasn't been received the first time through your loop.  Only one character has been received and that is why only one character is echoed.  You can't index into the buffer when the characters haven't been received yet.  By the second time through the loop, the remaining characters have been received because a relatively long time was spent echoing the first character.

Comment: @kkrambo, yeah,  you may be right.
I was under impression that the data from serial is read at once. Therefore, I thought that the variable  `UART0Buffer` is complete. That would be great.
How can I get a signal once the reading is done and the variable is complete?
Checking byte 7E at the beginning and then CHKSUM byte at the end of the data? I have also added `UART0_IRQHandler` where the receiving is handled for a better evaluation.

Comment: If the message length is always the same then you could change `if ( UART0Count != 0 )` to `if ( UART0Count >= MESSAGE_LENGTH )`.  But what you should do is implement a function containing a state machine to parse the frame like I described in my answer.

Comment: It is not a static length information but dynamic. And yes, I have actually a function for this. I have already done my best to follow the principal separation-of-concerns.I believe that I only need to implement an efficient framing procedure as per my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically designing a serial message driver.  Divide the design into layers.

The lowest layer is the UART driver that moves characters to and from the hardware UART.  The UART driver encapsulates all the knowledge about how to interface to the UART hardware.  This layer knows nothing of frames or messages, only characters.  It copies a transmit character to the TX register when a transmit character is available and the UART is ready to transmit.  It copies a received character from the UART RX register when one is available.  These actions are typically implemented in the UART interrupt service routine.  And typically, RAM circular buffers are used to store the TX and RX characters.

The next layer is for framing characters.  This layer is responsible for identifying the characters that delimit a frame.  This layer encapsulates all the knowledge about characters are delimited into frames.  This is typically implemented as a state machine that gets repeatedly called when characters are available in the RX buffer.   The state machine gets the next character from the RX buffer and processes it according to the current state.  States might include, for example, waiting_for_start_of_frame, copying_body_of_frame, and waiting_for_end_of_frame.  If the frame protocol includes a frame check sequence then this layer performs the check.  This layer doesn't attempt to interpret the meaning of frames, rather it just forms complete frames to be used by the next layer.

If your serial messages are large enough to span multiple frames then you might have a layer here that stitches frames together into messages.  Or if each message is a contained within a single frame then you probably don't need this layer.

At the top is the layer that actually interprets the message and performs the appropriate actions.  This layer doesn't know anything about the UART or the frame delimiters because all of that knowledge is encapsulated by the lower layers.

This answer has more tips, [Embedded C UART conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143429/embedded-c-uart-conventions/20146149#20146149)

Comment: I must say, I have already two layers. The code I am demonstrating is just for explaining where I stuck.

Comment: It is basically a Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern design: Model = action/event on every syntax, View = data buffer parser to extract correct syntax, Controller = UART read into the data buffer. We need a proper protocol to encapsulate the syntax.